# Erro tentando remover uma tabela temporária

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, stored-procedures, tabela-temporária

Possuo um serviço no qual realiza carga de dados de um ERP em um DW.
Sendo que ao origem dos dados é SQL Server 2008 R2 10.50.1600.1 e o servidor destino MS SQL Server 2008 10.0.5512.0 SP3.

O serviço executa uma *stored procedure* que gera tabelas temporárias que alimenta uma tabela física que gera a consulta que alimenta as tabelas do DW.

As tabelas temporárias cridas pela consulta mesmo após a exclusão se mantem carregadas no banco `TempDB`.

A consulta fica por horas em execução e não da carga no banco de destino.

Mesmo após executar o comando a abaixo as tabelas permanecem no banco TempDB:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tempdb..SysObjects WHERE Name LIKE'%#TEMP%')
    DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Já foi alterado o nível de permissão em se mantém o problema.

Erro apresentado:

> Cannot drop the table '#temp' because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permission. [SQLSTATE 42S02] (Error 3701).

Answer (score 5):

Wagner, você precisa testar se existe antes de excluir.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] like '#temp%') 
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #temp;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

Ela já foi apagada. Para evitar o erro, verifique antes se a operação pode ser exeutada:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #Temp
END
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/DropTransactional.sql).

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda deu certo.

Comment: @WagnerAntoniodasilva Dê uma olhada no [tour] você pode votar em todas as perguntas e respostas do site e escolher uma das respostas para sua pergunta como a que melhor ajudou você resolver o problema.